# C++ callback for c function

Tags: c++, c, arduino, esp32

Yes,,, I know there is many threads about this, and I've think I've read most of them, but either I don't understand the answers or I have not been able to adapt them to my "case".

Be aware, my background is electronic design, not software design so for some of you, my question maybe seem to be stupid, but... I am stuck.

I have designed a pcb board for iot purposes. It is based on a ESP32 module. I have 5 buttons connected to the ESP. ESP32-IDF is far to complicated for me so I've tried to go for the Ardiuno framework. Now it starts to get complicated.

To detect and debounce the buttons I created a C++ class called Button. A skeleton can be seen below.

```
class Button {
..
..

private:
  void memberCallback() {
    ...
  }



public:
  Button(const uint8_t gpio ) {
    ..
    attachInterrup(digitalPinToInterrupt(gpio), memberCallback, FALLING);
    ..
  }

..

}
```

I have not found any way to define "memberCallback" without not causing compile errors or not working at all.

This must be a common problem so, please suggest i solution :)

Edit. 
Seems like I not have expressed myself clearly enough, sorry. 
- I am aware that if I make memberCallback static, it will at least compile. Problem is that I planned to use 5 instances of this. A static callback means that all instances will run same code. 5 instances means 5 different interrupts. How do I identify them.

Comment: You can generally only use static methods as C callbacks, because C can't call through an object.

Comment: If you haven't understood the other answers – in particular the "you can't use a non-static member function as a C callback" part – it's very difficult to know how to answer this in a way that you would understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ESP32 Arduino Core has an example of how to do exactly this at

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/GPIO/FunctionalInterrupt

I'll quote code from it here:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <FunctionalInterrupt.h>

#define BUTTON1 16
#define BUTTON2 17

class Button
{
public:
    Button(uint8_t reqPin) : PIN(reqPin){
        pinMode(PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
        attachInterrupt(PIN, std::bind(&Button::isr,this), FALLING);
    };
    ~Button() {
        detachInterrupt(PIN);
    }

    void IRAM_ATTR isr() {
        numberKeyPresses += 1;
        pressed = true;
    }

private:
    const uint8_t PIN;
    volatile uint32_t numberKeyPresses;
    volatile bool pressed;
}
```

The important things are:

- `#include <FunctionalInterrupt.h>` - this gets you `std::bind()` and a slightly different `attachInterrupt()` declaration that makes this work
- Use `std::bind(&Button::isr,this)` to bind your interrupt handler to your object.
- Make sure you declare your interrupt handler as `IRAM_ATTR` to ensure the code for it will remain loaded in RAM.
- Make sure you declare any instance variables that you want to modify in the interrupt handler as `volatile` so that the C++ compiler will know they make change without warning.

`std::bind()` is a standard C++ library function; there's [documentation about it online](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

That said, I'm concerned about what you plan to do inside your interrupt handler.

Interrupt handlers need to run for a very brief amount of time, and they need to be very careful about calling other functions and making sure that data structures are in an inconsistent state. Unless you lock out interrupts (which you should do as little as possible) outside of the interrupt handler, data structures can easily be in inconsistent states.

The example in the Arduino Core is good - it just changes a couple of variables. Doing more than that - calling functions like `Serial.println()` or allocating memory or creating objects is not safe.

Comment: Thanks,, I have tried this solution ( std:bind solution ) before but it always gives me compile errors. So it does now. BUT, I created a small example with the code above and it works fine. Something must be wrong with my original PlatformIO project. Must check into this.

Comment: What's the compile error? I also use PlatformIO; I tested it with it before I posted.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the documentation of `attachInterrupt` it says that the ISR is a function taking no argument. Its type is `void(*)()` (or most likely actually `extern "C" void(*)()` but I haven’t researched the exact type thoroughly enough). Your `memberCallback` *looks* as if it does not take an argument but that is actually not true: in a [non-`static`] member function you got an implicit argument: `this`, the pointer to the object which is need to determine which `Button` object is used. The type of `memberCallback` is `void (Button::*)()` and is incompatible with `void(*)()`. Th implication is that you will *not* be able to use a [non-`static`] member function directly.

As was suggest in other answers, you could use a `static` member function. However, that has two problems:

1. The function has only access to `static` members (both function and variables).
2. The function won’t be `extern`"C"`.

You will need one function for every `Button` you want to register. For just one `Button` that would look like that:

```
class Button
{
    // ....
public:
    void memberCallback();
    Button(int gpio, Button*& ptr, void(*isr)()) {
        ptr = this;
        attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(gpio), isr, FALLING);
    }
};

Button* button1;
extern "C" void button1ISR() {
    button1ISR->memberCallback();
}

// create you Button somewhere, e.g.:
int main() {
    Button b1(gpio, button1, button1ISR);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: attachInterrupt is a C++ function

Comment: @Juraj: OK. That means the `extern "C" might need to be dropped depending on how the ISR is declared. Everything else remains, though.

Comment: Attachinterrup is a c function from the arduino library.

Comment: @Ig.lindstrom: I figured that. However, a 5min online search didn’t yield the detailed declaration allowing to decide if the `extern "C"` is needed or not (although in practice I don’t know any platform where it does not work when used wrong).

Comment: There's actually a correct way to do this that doesn't require external functions or static class methods. It's even documented in the ESP32 Arduino core. Answer is below.

Comment: @romkey. Missing your solution. Can you please post a pointer to the solution?

Comment: It's the one that starts with "The ESP32 Arduino core"... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60657202/2670348

Answer (score 0):

Make your `memberCallback` function static. Change your code to this:

```
class Button {
..
..

private:
  static void memberCallback() {
    ...
  }



public:
  Button(const uint8_t gpio ) {
    ..
    attachInterrup(digitalPinToInterrupt(gpio), memberCallback, FALLING);
    ..
  }

..

}
```